# Why are the generic type bounds lost when used in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

```
public interface Entity {
}

public class EntityImpl implements Entity {
}

public interface Service<T extends Entity> {
    T find(int id);
    Optional<T> findOptional(int id);
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service<EntityImpl> {
    @Override
    public EntityImpl find(int id) {
        return new EntityImpl();
    }
    @Override
    public Optional<EntityImpl> findOptional(int id) {
        return Optional.of(new EntityImpl());
    }
}

public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service = new ServiceImpl();
        Entity e1 = service.find(1);
        Optional<Entity> opt = service.findOptional(1);
        Entity e2 = service.findOptional(1).get(); //compile error
    }
}
```

I can get the correct Optional type without problems if saving the optional, but if I want to call a method on the returned generic Optional it seems the compiler is loosing the type bounds and I get just an Object. In the e2-line I get the following error from javac:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to Entity
```

Why is it loosing the type information? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are using a raw type. You'd better go with:

```
Service<EntityImpl> service = new ServiceImpl();
```

Also, `service.findOptional(1)` returns a `Optional<EntityImpl>`, not a `Optional<Entity>`.